# I have a laptop which is running Ubuntu which I want to uninstall so I can install Windows instead

Tags: system-installation, windows

I have just acquired a laptop which is running Ubuntu. I have no experience with Ubuntu so I want to uninstall it and install Windows instead. I have no idea how to do this so if anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of Windows CD/DVD installs of which I am aware should give you an ability to choose where to install. With ubuntu installed, the drive may not be seen and if this is the case it may be necessary to work with a brand specific HD software to prepare the drive for a windows installation(most of these softwares can be found at the HD makers website). Please be aware that any data on the drive will be completely erased due to a formatting in either case.